How to obtain environment variable from a Firebase deploy?
I have a React project deployed in firebase. Sadly i forgot the .env.local variables, and as such i can't run the project from my local machine anymore.
Is there any way to extract the environment varibles from a firebase depoy? (I am not talking about firebaseConfig object)
Thanks i advance...
Missing values from environment variable
